# Express not evaluating id string correctly

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

i'm writing an express app and i'm trying to add a frineds list on a profile page.
The user has an array of friends (which is just an id to another user)
when evaluating if this id is equal to a users id it isn't working?

When printing out they seem identical..

It's the '!=' expression that doesn't seem to be doing anything.

users is a list of all users

currentUser is the user logged in currently

friends is the array list of currentUser

```
<div class="container px-4 py-5" id="custom-cards">
 <h2 class="pb-2 border-bottom">Add friends</h2>
  <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-lg-3 align-items-stretch g-4 py-5">
     <% users.forEach(async function(user) {%> 

    <% if(user.email != currentUser.email){ %>

    <% currentUser.friends.forEach(async function(friend) { %> 
      <p><%= friend %></p>
      <p><%= user %></p>

    <% if (friend._id != user._id) {%>


    <div class="col">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
        <img src="<%= user.image.url %>" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><%= user.username %></h5>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <% } %> 

    
    <%})%> 
    <%} %>
    <%}) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

guessing the ._id field is from MongoDB which is an instance of ObjectId, since you can't compare two objects with the equality operator, you need to call _id.toString() !== _id.toString() which will convert both ObjectId's to strings which can be compared with equality operator.

In your case it would be

```js
<% if (friend._id.toString() !== user._id.toString() {%>
```

[You should always use the strict equality operator to avoid confusing situations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality)